# Trouble setting a height to a display:table element in firefox, works in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

What I am trying to do: 
Set the `<body>` tag as `display:table` and my header/content/footer as `display:table-row`s. I also want `<body>` to be the size of the screen, the child elements will show scrollbar if needed.

I do this by setting

```
body{
  display:table;
  height:100%
}
```

This works in chrome, but in firefox the height of the body is the height of the screen. Is this as expected or is this a firefox issue? Is there a way to achieve this while using table? It used to work without table, but I need the footer to not appear on occasion, so I need my content to grow as needed, and it seems to work nicely in chrome.

You can see this on my (alpha) site at [sportmenow.com](http://sportmenow.com)

Comment: You write  Set the <body> tag as `display:row` - don't you mean `display:table` ?

Comment: @Danield yup, my bad, "%body" is table, and ".body" is row, in haml parlance

Comment: Your layout is massively wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this bug report, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26617#c14, it seems when the element is using *display: table-row*, Firefox treat height as min-height, that's why you only found problem in Firefox.

On the other hand, if you already know the height of your header / footer before hand, you could use *position: fixed* with fix value in *top* and *bottom* attribute to layout your page instead.

In short, please try replace your CSS on your *.body* and *.footer* like this.

```
.body { 
    display: block; 
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 60px; 
    bottom: 92px; 
    padding: 6px;
}
.footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background: #FFFFFF;   
}
```

This will work consistently on both Firefox and Chrome.

However, when you hide your footer, you will need to use javascript to update CSS attribute "bottom" to 0 on your .body element.

```
$('.body').css({'bottom':'0'});
```

Comment: While I might go with flexbox after all, this does appear to be the closest answer to the question(why firefox but not chrome)

Answer (score 3):

I've provided two solutions below, the first is more structured, the second follows your design pattern.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/x3Pw6/8/)

Why not implement more structured HTML which follows a more semantically correct pattern and structure of `table->row->cell`:

```
<header>
    <section></section>
</header>
<article>
    <section></section>
</article>
<footer>
    <section></section>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    display:table;
}
header, footer, article {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header, footer {
    height:50px;
    background:black;
}
section {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
    height:100%;
}
```

**However..** If you dont care about this so much, you can simply use `display:table` on your `body` element and then the below- the limitation being that each section will collapse unless it has content (even only `nbsp;`)

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/x3Pw6/9/)

HTML

```
<header>headerContent</header>
<article>mainContent</article>
<footer>footerContent</footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    display:table;
}
header, footer, article {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header, footer {
    height:50px;
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: great example. This could be achieved vh (viewport height) unit however this would fail on older browser support.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the height of a `display:table` element in firefox. However, to use the full browser window, you may have to specify the height of the `html` element too:

```
html { height:100%; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhJ7F/)

Comment: Interesting, perhaps I am missing some more subtlities from my site. I do actually do this, and according to the computed tab of the inspector, my html is 950 px high and my body 3.5k, so the body is a lot taller than the html.

Comment: OK, I had a bit of a dig around. It looks like your problems come from having the structure `display:table > display:table-row > display:inline-block`. I tried changing the children of `div.body` to be `display:table-cell`, as they should be, but the map popped out because it's absolutely positioned somehow. Nonetheless I think the body was able to size itself correctly with `display:table-cell` grandchildren.

Comment: That said, please consider @csuwldcat's suggestion to use flexbox. Given that your current code uses css `calc`, `flexbox` has mostly better support. (See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com); the only browser to support `calc` but *not* `flexbox` is IE9.)

Comment: I was using it primarily for the table-row effect for the footer, to make the body expand if i do not have a footer. Perhaps I should take a look at flexbox as suggested. This is not really my forte, and display-table helped me once before so I started with that.

Comment: [This css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be helpful. Remember, you can nest flex layouts, so for example create a vertical stack, then a horizontal row inside the middle box.

Answer (score 1):

To set any element to 100% of its parent's height, the parent element must have a defined, non-percentage height (px, em, etc.), or it an all ancestor elements must be 100% height. For example, if your element was the first child of the `body`, you could set it to 100% height with the following CSS:

```
html, body, #my_element {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you were to set a parent to a specific height, then the target element to 100%, the target element would be that height as well. Imagine you had an element with an ID of `element_parent`, that contained your target element:

```
#element_parent {
  height: 500px;
}

#my_element {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In the above example would mean that `my_element` would expand to the full 500px that its parent is set to.

Comment: Please check the site I mention, rather than copy-pasting wikipedia or w/e. I already do do this, and it works fine on chrome, but not firefox

Comment: @KarthikT I wasn't pasting from Wikipedia, I was telling you what I know (I work at Mozilla, the link is from MDN, a well-known dev resource)

Comment: @KarthikT yeah, just checked your site in Firefox and Chrome, they look identical. If you don't believe me, I can do screenshots. Why are you using a table instead of flexbox? You didn't say anything about old IE (less than 10). If that's not a problem, just use flexbox, it's the intended tech for this use-case.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit rude, I was just dissapointed that the answer provided was quite generic, and contained information that I was already aware of and had implemented. It is odd that you (And an upvoter) are not seeing the difference I am seeing. I recently updated to 28 on mac, and the list is still unscrollable and full sized.